# Would SSD improve thrashing?

Tags: ssd, thrashing

I understand [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29) (computer's virtual memory subsystem in a constant state of paging) is basically problem of not enough memory.

**But besides adding more RAM, would adding a SSD to a HDD or replacing HDD with a SSD help with thrashing?**

Comment: If your system is indeed thrashing, then it would better to solve/reduce the thrashing, than go looking for a faster storage device.  Or is this a homework question?

Comment: Just curiosity since I just learn about SSD and I what more information about it.

Answer (score 1):

Because SSD have no mechanical rotation parts you don't hear anything. Only a HDD indicator would tell you heavy usage.

SSDs are very fast that can provide data from the pagefile very fast without slowdown the system.

If you run of of RAM very often, please add more RAM to avoid unnecessary writes to SSD, so that the SSD can be used longer before the flash modules reach their max number of writes they can handle.

Comment: But would SSD help with thrashing?

Comment: yes, because it can read /write data from a large file very fast (linear reads/writes are several hundreds of MB/s for SSDs).

Comment: I thought SSD writing is slow in SSD.

Comment: not my Samsung SSD. I sometimes also need a lot of RAM and sometimes use 12GB on my 8GB laptop and because of the SSD I noticed no slowdown.

Comment: Thanks magincandre of your insight.  I just learned about SSD in my OS class and I would told that writing is slow SSD.  It's good to know that is not always the case.  :)